# Window closing, shouldn't be

Tags: javascript

I would like my pop- up layer to stay open after reloading parent. I have no closing code I can see for my pop- up layer? My onclick function works perfectly to update my cart on main page, but closes layer at the same time, which I do not want. What do I need to keep pop- up layer open after refresh? Thank you!

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function ReloadParent(url) {
 parent.parent.document.location = url; 
   }
  </script>


<button onclick="ReloadParent('index_5.php')">Click me</button>
```

Comment: I'm assuming the missing `>` is a typo?

Comment: Do you have a popup blocker enabled? Maybe it sees what you're doing as intrusive and/or dangerous.

Comment: I may be wrong, but if you refresh any web page, any children objects in the DOM would be deleted, including any pop-up. Perhaps you can use some sort of Javascript to update a specific parent element?

Comment: Yes, Doorknob. Typo on Copy/ Paste. My Apologies!

Comment: Yes flem, I did have pop- up blocker on. I took it off with same result. Thanks, though!

Comment: Typo fixed. Thanks, Doorknob. Still an unwanted closing.

Answer (score 0):

Since the dialog box is not a separate page or tab, you cannot avoid it being destroyed when the page refreshes.  Thus, you'll have to either keep track of the properties of the dialog and regenerate it when the page reloads - or instead, avoid refreshing the page and partially update it using AJAX or other dynamic HTML methods.

Comment: Layer still closes, unfortunately. Thanks for trying!

Comment: So when you say Popup Layer, you mean a Javascript generated dialog box and NOT a separate browser window/tab?

Comment: Thanks Rake36! Yes, exactly. Javascript. The idea being the user does not have to wait for a page load. And, it's still SEO friendly. Not to mention the possibility of Pop- Up Blocker interference. Thanks again, for your help and interest.

Comment: Oh, well, in that case, you're going to have to come up with a method for persisting the dialog box between page loads (whether via storing the properties and then rebuilding or some other method).  My recommendation would be to not reload the page at all and dynamically adjust the page underneath via Ajax/Javascript, etc. (Edited my answer)